# Unknown setting 'hosts' for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, exec, logstash

I'm trying to run logstash config files on my mac but everytime I do so, I get this error:

```
 'Unknown setting 'hosts' for elasticsearch {:level=>:error} 
  Error: Something is wrong with your configuration.
  You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
  use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
  to restart a running system.'
```

I am retrieving JIRA data and send it to elasticsearch, but even this simple task returns an error. Here is my code:

```
 input{
        exec {
             command => "curl -u username:password https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?maxResults=10"
              interval => 300
               }
       }
  output{
       elasticsearch{
             hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
             index => "test"
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of Logstash (pre-2.0), just rename [`hosts` to `host`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-host) and you'll be fine:

```
   output{
       elasticsearch{
             host => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
             index => "test"
        }
   }
```

Comment: Helped me too, in my case I was using a newer version but following a tutorial based on an older version. Changed host to hosts, and it worked great. :)

Comment: I am using 6.3.2, but am still getting the error: `Unknown setting 'host' for elasticsearch`

Comment: @RayKim you need to use `hosts` instead of `host`

Comment: @Val I am using `hosts` instead of `host`, but am still getting the error.

Comment: @RayKim which version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: @Val 6.3.2 ,,,,,

Comment: @RayKim feel free to create a new question describing your issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Val for the info! I found out that I had multiple logstash directories on my mac and it was using an older version  (1.x) instead of 2.3. I just deleted the older directory and the code worked!